# What is the difference bewteen ngSwitch & ngPlural - Angular

Tags: angular

I've surfed Angular documentation and cant find what is the difference between them
also i've toggled between them in this example : https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngplural
and got the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ngSwitch conditionally adds/removes DOM elements depends on any value (string, number, boolean)
ngSwitch: any

ngPlural conditionally adds/removes DOM sub-trees depends on numeric value only
ngPlural: number;

Html file

```
<p>
 I have {{count1}} items, but I could also say 

 <span [ngSwitch]="count1">
 <ng-template ngSwitchCase="zero">there are no items.</ng-template>
 <ng-template ngSwitchCase="one">there is one item.</ng-template>
 <ng-template ngSwitchCase="2">there are four items.</ng-template>
 <ng-template ngSwitchCase="many">there are many items.</ng-template>
 <ng-template ngSwitchCase="other">there are some items.</ng-template>
 </span>
</p>

<p>
 I have {{count}} items, but I could also say 

 <span [ngPlural]="count">
 <ng-template ngPluralCase="zero">there are no items.</ng-template>
 <ng-template ngPluralCase="one">there is one item.</ng-template>
 <ng-template ngPluralCase="2">there are four items.</ng-template>
 <ng-template ngPluralCase="many">there are many items.</ng-template>
 <ng-template ngPluralCase="other">there are some items.</ng-template>
 </span>
</p>
```

ts.file

```
export class AppComponent {
  count = "zero" // ngPlural when I give string values it goes to default statement
  count1 = "one" // ngSwitch works here perfectly
}
```

Comment: So why to use ngPlural ?

Answer (score 0):

[ngPluralCase] Creates a view that will be added/removed from the parent ngPlural when the given expression matches the plural expression according to CLDR rules.

Refer this website [CLDR Rules](http://cldr.unicode.org/index/cldr-spec/plural-rules)

Comment: so what is the difference

Comment: @OmarHasan Please go through CLDR Rules then you will understand. As per my understanding 'plural' is useful in multi lingual projects.

Answer (score -1):

`ngSwitch` conditionally adds/removes DOM elements depends on **boolean (expression)** value

`ngPlural` conditionally adds/removes DOM sub-trees depends on **numeric** value

Comment: Boolean value means expression, Expression always returns true or false, It is switch case statement